# Scope JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript. In the code below, when I log in, I try to get the user info from database and store in `user` object. However, when I check the user in the `commandManager` scope, it turns `null`. How can I make `user` not `null`?

Here is the code:

```
function LogInCommand(username, password) {
  return new Command(function (user) {
    api
      .logIn(username, password)
      .then(function (data) {
        user = data;
        console.log(user);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}

function createCommandManager() {
  var user = null;

  return {
    execute: function (command, ...args) {
      command.execute(user, ...args);
    },
    user: user
  };
}

var commandManager = createCommandManager();

commandManager.execute(new LogInCommand("andy@gmail.com", "123456"));
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(commandManager.user);
}, 10000);
```

Here is the result:

```
{age: 21, connection: null, email: "andy@gmail.com", name: "andy", pendingConnection: null, …}
null
```

Thanks all of you for your helps!

Comment: The code seems incomplete. `commandManager` is undefiend at the line `commandManager.execute(new LogInCommand("andy@gmail.com", "123456"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you change your `user` variable directly. It will break reference and it will not work. 
If you want to do it with your way. You can change your code like the below.

```
function LogInCommand(username, password) {
  return new Command(function (initialData) {
    api
      .logIn(username, password)
      .then(function (data) {
        initialData.user = data;
        console.log(initialData.user);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}

function createCommandManager() {
  var initialData = {
     user: null,
  };

  return {
    execute: function (command, ...args) {
      command.execute(initialData, ...args);
    },
    data: initialData
  };
}

commandManager.execute(new LogInCommand("andy@gmail.com", "123456"));
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(commandManager.data.user);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: `console.log(user);` will cause an error because there is no `user` variable in scope.

Comment: @Titus thanks for the correction. I have changed the issue.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan Can you explain to me why it breaks the reference? I still don't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: In javascript, When you use `pass by value` technique. Changing the argument inside the function doesn’t affect the variable passed from outside the function. But when you use `pass by reference` technique. Changing the argument inside the function affects the variable passed from outside the function. In Javascript, objects and arrays follow pass by reference. Actually you were trying `pass by reference`. But the issue is if you assign your arguments directly, it will break the reference and it will not affect the variable passed from outside the function. That's why we wrapped the variable.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan Oh i got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

One the things that are ovious in the code are that there not closed in the correct wy and that there are command that are missing.